# How to use Linq for foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a table that shows all users based on the selected program.

Programs:

- Id (key),
- program (string)

ProgramUsers:

- Id (key),
- username,
- program (foreign key),
- programaccess

Client input: program (string)

```
var programUsers = context.ProgramUsers
                     .Include("Program")
                     .Where(b => b.Program == clientInput.Program)
                     .ToList();
```

Of course, since `b.Program` is an `int` and `clientInput.Program` is a `string`, this does not work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I don't think your `include` should have a hard-coded string in it. That is including the literal word "Program", not related entities in the database.

Comment: If you googled `ef core foreign key`, you'd find many resources like [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx#google_vignette). so check documentations first~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `ProgramUsers` class needs a `ProgramId` property and a `Program` reference property.
2. The `Program` needs a `ProgramUsers` collection navigation property.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class ProgramUsers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Program")]
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }

    public Program Program { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Program")]
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProgramUser> ProgramUsers { get; set; }
}
```

To configure in [Fluent API](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx) if you are using Entity Framework Core:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ProgramUser>()
            .HasRequired<Program>(x => x.Program)
            .WithMany(g => g.ProgramUsers)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(x => x.ProgramId);
```

And to get the related entity for `ProgramUsers` in your query, assume that you are trying to get the program users by program name:

```cs
var programUsers = context.ProgramUsers
                     .Include(x => x.Program)
                     .Where(b => b.Program.ProgramName == clientInput.Program)
                     .ToList();
```

Reference: [Data Annotations - ForeignKey Attribute in EF 6 & EF Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)